# Android Jelly Bean More Option Button

Tags: android, android-button, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-keypad

I use Galaxy Nexus and it hasn't any button. But others have some special buttons. For example home,menu,back and search. I am developing an android app and for example I want to use menu button. How can I do this ? How can I add one or more keys on bottom line ?

For example Whatsapp using this. I start whatsapp and I see 4 button, back, home, apps and consecutive three-point. If I click this three-point button , new tab opened and there are few options here.

I want to use this logic how can I do this ?

Note: I don't know how can I pronounced these buttons name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check this from the documentation in order to get Menu into your app

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

It's quite simple, just override few methods...

Comment: Hey, I want to ask something. I read this document and I do it. For 2.3.x device, I click menu button, my menu shown. But Galaxy Nexus (4.1.1) hasn't menu button and my menu doesn't show. What can I do ? How can I do this visible ?

Comment: Well, starting from honeycomb the concept has been changed. Google has created the ActionBar class to replace the old menu. Please check this <http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu>. It describes how to do exactly in your case. Pratically you have yo use the new actionbar (with the actionbar compatibility library, an external jar), that can simulate the action bar below Honeycomb

Answer (score 0):

you're developing a web application?
if you're, you can using jquery mobile which already provides the keys/buttons for you. otherwise you have to create the button on the app. CMIIW